# What is the time complexity of the Edmonds-Karp algorithm for finding a maximum cardinality matching in bipartite graphs?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, bipartite-matching

What is the time complexity of the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) (**not** the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)) for finding a maximum cardinality matching in bipartite graphs? Is it still $O(|V||E|^2)$, or it has a better time complexity in this special case?

Comment: What do you think? Do you have reason to believe that the algorithm is faster for maximum cardinality matching?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The Hopcroft-Karp algorithm can be seen as a special case of Dinic's algorithm, which has the time complexity of $O(|V|^2|E|)$, while the time complexity of the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm is $O(|E|\sqrt{|V|})$. So I wonder if the Edmonds-Karp algorithm also has a better performance in this case.